# TestCafe get version

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to get the current installed version of TestCafe on my Node.js. 
I tried:

```
    let testcafe = null;

    createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338, void 0, true)
        .then(tc => {
            testcafe     = tc;
    .......
        })
        .then(() => {
            return runner
                .src([__basedir + '/tests/temp.js'])
                .browsers(myBrowser)
                .screenshots(screnshotpath, true)
                .reporter('allure')
                .run()
                .then(failedCount => {
                    console.log( "Testcafe Version" + testcafe.version);
                    testcafe.close();
    .......
```

But this is undefined. Is there any other way possible?

Answer (score 3):

When used programmatically, it doesn't seem like Testcafe has an option to get the version like you might have when using the cli, with the `-v` option.

The easiest way I can think of is to import *package.json*:

```
const { version } = require('testcafe/package.json');
console.log("Testcafe Version " + version);
```